# Select one of each

Tags: sql

How can I get all the countries from the DB, from this table:

```
city          | country  | info
Jerusalem     | Israel   | Capital
Tel Aviv      | Israel   | 
New York      | USA      | Biggest
Washington DC | USA      | Capital
Berlin        | Germany  | Capital
```

How can I get, using SQL, the countries only: Israel, USA, Germany?

Comment: Do you mean you want to fetch all countries, but without any duplicates?

Comment: Without anymore details you'd use `select distinct country from yourtable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database server are you using?

Assuming that the top row is the column name and you are using MySQL then you should be able to just do

```
"SELECT distinct(country) FROM <table-name>;"
```

This is probably in the documentation for the database software that you are using.